# Image not refreshing on jquery load

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a form that uploads image file then updates image value in database successfully via ajax. However when I try to `.load` the `profile_pic.php` which echos the above image tag, the image is not updated on the webpage. I don't want to refresh page. The echo statement from the php is outputting the same src path which already exists in the dom. I need it to remain this way. Can anyone recommend a better approach?

```
<div class="actor-profile-pic">
    <img id="profilepic" src="uploads/jgunzblazin">                     
</div>

<form id="file-form" name="uploadpic" class="infoHeader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242888" />
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="uploadpic" value="Submit" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#file-form").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "actor_profile.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                $(".actor-profile-pic").load("../profile_pic.php #profilepic"); 
            }           
       });
    }));
});
```

Comment: So what is the `profile_pic.php` supposed to send back now? Html or just the image link? Is the response supposed to replace `<img id="profilepic" src="uploads/jgunzblazin">`? Your explanation is a bit hard to follow what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, the response replaces existing img tag with the same img tag from response. I think that is the problem. The image will not update if the src is replaced with the same src.

Comment: I currently set the image name in the path to the $username. So any image uploaded will always have the same name. Hence why the image is not updating. I bet if I set image name to random name - it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out the image was not updating because I was updating the img src tag with the same img src value that was being echoed from /profile_pic.php. Once I change name of file name the image updated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your php file after successful upload and database insert returns *(echos)* the picture's **relative-path/filename** (eg. images/my-photo.jpg); which ultimately is passed to the **data** variable of success callback function.

In this case, you could also try:

```
success: function(data){
    $(".actor-profile-pic img").attr("src",data); 
}
```

Please check if this works for you.